# Relational algebra , tried everything, just don't know how to do this

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

The following relational tables/schemes are given:

In **bold** is the primary key, in *Italics* is foreign key:

-City(**Name**,Country,Population)

-Venue(**VID**,Capacity,*Name*)

-Concert(**KID**,*ID*,*DID*,duration)

-Performer(**ID**,*KID*,age,name)

-Ticket(**TID**,*KID*,price,type)

Now my assignment is to find all the concerts where there were more VIP tickets than other tickets. VIP is of the attribute type, in tickets. I honestly have thought about this problem a while. My main idea what to group KID,Type,count(*) in (tickets) and somehow add the tickets of type != VIP and select where that is less than VIP tickets, but I just don;t know how to do that formally..

Comment: There are multiple versions of "relational algebra". Please give a reference to the one you are supposed to use.

Comment: Please show what you have tried for partial solutions. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
  SELECT CONCERT.NAME FROM CONCERT 
      INNER JOIN TICKET ON CONCERT.KID = TICKET.KID
  WHERE 
      (SELECT COUNT(CONCERT.KID) FROM CONCERT 
          INNER JOIN TICKET ON CONCERT.KID = TICKET.KID WHERE TYPE = 'VIP') >
      (SELECT COUNT(CONCERT.KID) FROM CONCERT 
          INNER JOIN TICKET ON CONCERT.KID = TICKET.KID WHERE TYPE != 'VIP')
```