# Relational Algebra rule for column transformation

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

What is the **rule** for the transformation of a column in *Relational Algebra*? For example, I want to divide all values of a column with the average of that column. I can get average using aggregate rule. But cannot find the rule for column manipulation.
P.S: I am interested in the rule (like \Pi is used for projection).

Comment: Hi. There's no standard approach to this. Also there's no single relational algebra'language, so give a reference to yours. Note that updating the value of a base variable is not an arithmetic operation, it is an operation of a programming language.

Comment: What do you mean by "rule" exactly? "Algebra operator"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard approach to this. Also there's no single relational algebra, so you should give a reference to yours.

Suppose you supply the division operator on values of a column in the form of a constant base relation called `DIVIDE` holding tuples where `dividend`/`divisor`=`quotient`. I'll use the simplest algebra, with headings that are sets of attribute names. Assume we have input relation `R` with column `c` & average `A`. We want the relation like `R` but with each column `c` value set to its original value divided by `A`.

This version starts from the simplest specification expression & mechanically converts to algebra:

```
/* rows where
EXISTS dividend [R(dividend, A) & DIVIDE(dividend, A, c)]
*/
PROJECT c, A (
        RENAME c\dividend (R)
    NATURAL JOIN
        RENAME divisor\A quotient\c (DIVIDE))
```

This version has a less concise specification expression mechanically derived from concise algebra:

```
/* rows where
EXISTS quotient [
        quotient = c
    &   THERE EXISTS c [
            R(c, A) & DIVIDE(c, A, quotient)]
*/
RENAME quotient\c
    PROJECT quotient, A (
        R NATURAL JOIN RENAME dividend\c divisor\A (DIVIDE))
```

See also [Relational algebra - recode column values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35283565/3404097).