# How to subtract values form two columns in RelaX (online relational algebra calculator)

Tags: relational-algebra

Is there any way to subtract values from two different columns using RelaX (an relational algebra online calculator)? I have tried using projection, group by, as well as a few examples I saw here on SO. I am trying to subtract the average wage from value the of the wage of employees.

Comment: Hi. That is in their help page. You could have found that yourself. I don't see a [so] answer & I wanted to address language vs algebra so I wrote one. Beware: Lack of research merits downvotes. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Re code questions see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The [RelaX](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/index.htm) projection operator takes a list of expressions giving the column values of each row returned. Those expressions can be just column names but they don't have to be. (As with an SQL `select` clause.)

From [the help link](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/help.htm):

> projection

> Expressions can be used to create more complex statements using one or more columns of a single row.
>
> ```
> pi c.id, lower(username)->user, concat(firstname, concat(' ', lastname))->fullname (
>         ρ c ( Customer )
>     )
> ```

> **Value expressions**
>   With most operators you can use a value-expression which connects one or more columns of a single row to calculate a new value. This is possible for:
>
> - the projection creating a new column (make sure to give the column a name)
> - the selection any expression evaluating to boolean can be used
> - for the joins any expression evaluating to boolean can be used; note that the rownum() expression always represents the index of the lefthand relation

**PS** RelaX is properly a query language, not an algebra. Its "value expressions" are not evaluated to a value before the call. That begs the question of how we would implement a language using an algebra.

From [Is multiplication allowed in relational algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321855/3404097):

> Some so-called "algebras" are really languages because the expressions don't only represent the results of operators being called on values. Although it is possible for an algebra to have operand values that represent expressions and/or relation values that contain names for themselves.

> The projection that takes attribute expressions begs the question of its implementation given an algebra with projection only on a relation value and attribute names. This is important in an academic setting because a question may be wanting you to actually figure out how to do that, or because the difficulty of a question is dependent on the operators available. So find out what algebra you are supposed to use.
>
> We can introduce an operator on attribute values when we only have basic relation operators taking attribute names and relation values. Each such operator can be associated with a relation value that has an attribute for each operand and an attribute for the result. The relation holds the tuples where the result value is equal to the the result of the operator called on the operand values. (The result is functionally dependent on the operands.)

From [Relational Algebra rule for column transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49596872/3404097):

> Suppose you supply the division operator on values of a column in the form of a constant base relation called `DIVIDE` holding tuples where `dividend`/`divisor`=`quotient`. I'll use the simplest algebra, with headings that are sets of attribute names. Assume we have input relation `R` with column `c` & average `A`. We want the relation like `R` but with each column `c` value set to its original value divided by `A`.

> ```
> /* rows where
> EXISTS dividend [R(dividend) & DIVIDE(dividend, A, c)]
> */
> PROJECT c (
>         RENAME c\dividend (R)
>     NATURAL JOIN
>         RENAME quotient\c (
>             PROJECT dividend, quotient (SELECT divisor=A (DIVIDE))))
> ```

From [Relational algebra - recode column values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35283565/3404097):

> To introduce specific values into a relational algebra expression you have to have a way to write table literals. Usually the necessary operators are not made explicit, but on the other hand algebra exercises frequently use some kind of notation for example values.