# Relational algebra - SQL MAX per value

Tags: relational-database, aggregate-functions, relational-algebra

I am making up exercises for myself and stumbled across this question:

Given this example relation:

`Person(name, birthyear)`

Find the relational algebra expression to find the youngest person per name. For example, you have the entries:

`(A, 1), (A,2), (B,3), (B,4), (C,5), (C,6)`

Expression returns:

`(A,1), (B,3), (C,5)`

My solution:

`ρ p1 (Person) - σ p1.name = p2.name AND p1.birthYear > p2.birthYear (ρ p2 (Person))`

Do I accomplish my goal? So yes, will I have doubles and how to elliminate them if I do?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please give a reference to which of the many versions of "relational algebra" you are using. And:  A relation is a set of rows. A value can't be in a set twice. So no duplicates. And: You need a join. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) and [this answer that it links to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097).

Comment: PS Read about [mcve]s: work through an example and include it. Check out [RelaX](http://138.232.66.66/ra/).