# What would be the result of this operation on these tables?

Tags: database, join, relation, relational-algebra

```
Enroll (table):

cid        sid    grade    gradepoint
CS425      001    A        4.0
CS595      001    B        3.0
CS595      002    A        4.0
EE401      001    A        4.0
EE401      002    B        3.0
EE401      004    A        4.0
PHYS571    002    C        2.0
PHYS571    004    A        4.0
```

Using relational algebra, the operation is (excuse the lack of greek letters, I don't know how to add them on SO):

```
select_(Enroll.gradepoint<x.gradepoint)^Enroll.cid=x.cid (Enroll x rho_x(Enroll))
```

Basicaly, it is saying to do a cartesian product of the Enroll table with itself (renaming the second instance of Enroll to "x"), then select only the rows where the cid matches (of course) and **where the gradepoint is lower than itself**. But this makes no sense. Wouldn't this just result in an empty set?

Comment: Could it be that in relational algebra the *order* of the terms in the selection predicate actually matters??

Comment: No, @JohnSmithy1266, the order in the σ selection doesn't matter, nor in the π projection. There is no 'column order' in RA and access is by attribute name only. Neither is there dot-prefix attribute naming usually (are you actually using SQL?) -- what version of RA are you using? I just can't follow your notation. By ρ (rho) renaming relation `Enroll` to `x`, I guess you get two copies of each attribute arising from the cartesian product. You're matching on `cid` only, so you'll get different `sid`s, `grade`s, `gradepoint`s.

Comment: @AntC I dind't know there were different variations of RA. I'm using the standard taught in a grad school course, I would assume.

Comment: There is no one "RA" (relational algebra). They differ even in what a relation is. *Give a reference to your RA*. (Rho seems to rename *a relation* which doesn't make sense even if relations contain their own name, but that's the kind of idiotic so-called RAs SQL apologists define.) A select/restrict condition evaluates to true/false, so why would order matter? (It *could*, per contained operators.) [Every query has a meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097), your paraphrase is wrong. *Where and how are you stuck*?? Please google 'stackexchange homework'. See [ask].

Comment: Here is a link to the type of relational algebra that I am using: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/relational_algebra.htm

Comment: Thanks. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. Please address my other request: show your work & where & how you are stuck. Note that *your expression is not using the same algebra as your link*. Re your 1st comment, what is the "it" you mean when you say "could it be"? "It" seems to be some kind of cause of some kind of *problem*? PS  1. You can google 'unicode' with 'join', 'rho', etc then cut & paste. 2. https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm (Did you try to find an online algebra evaluator?) 3. tutorialspoint is a poor information source; that page is an example.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? The result *value*? The result *meaning*? Please edit to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say operator `rename n (r)` returns a table value like `r` but with new attribute names like the old ones prefixed with `n.`. Then we have:

```
/* rows where
    (cid, sid, grade, gradepoint) in Enroll
and (x.cid, x.sid, x.grade, x.gradepoint) in Enroll
and gradepoint < x.gradepoint and cid = x.cid
*/
restrict gradepoint < x.gradepoint and cid = x.cid (
    Enroll times rename x (Enroll)
    )
```

(Which are rows of the form `(cid, sid, grade, gradepoint, x.cid, x.sid, x.grade, x.gradepoint)`.)

Unfortunately that comment doesn't say anything about *the business situation*. So neither does the table. But suppose in our case `(cid, sid, grade, gradepoint) in Enroll` when `in course`*`cid`*`student`*`sid`*`got grade`*`grade`*`& grade point average`*`gradepoint`*. (This is the table's *(characteristic) predicate* in business terms.) Then by replacing the `in` we get that that query is also:

```
/* rows where
    in course cid student sid got grade grade & grade point average gradepoint
and in course x.cid student x.sid got grade x.grade & grade point average x.gradepoint
and gradepoint < x.gradepoint and cid = x.cid
*/
```

Each row in a table value (constant/variable or query result) makes a statement from plugging it into the table's predicate. (And each absent row states the negation/`not` of the statement from plugging it into the predicate.) The designer gives the constant/variable predicates and the query result predicate comes from those & the relation operators. (`restrict` & `join`s (including `times` & `intersect`) introduce `and`, `project` introduces `there exists`, `union` introduces `or`, `minus` introduces `and not`, etc.)

Here, the statement involves one course and two gradepoints, each belonging to a different student. So there's no "where the gradepoint is lower than itself".

[Forming a relational algebra query from an English description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318188/3404097)
[Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

(A so-called "algebra operator" like you mention to "rename" a value is really a *programming language non-terminal* for *assignment to a variable*. That is orthogonal to algebra values & operators. Such muddling arises from unclear thinking, typical of SQL apologetics.)

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer but I'm a little confused. I think you might have some erroneous code designation, for example around the word "got" or "in course".

Comment: Your comment is not clear. But "in course..." is not code, it is *English*, it is a template what a row says about the business situation. Rows that make a true statement go in the table. We say, it is what the table means; it is the *(characteristic) predicate* of the table in business terms. Did you read the links? I'll edit when I can. *Please* read your title & question and see that it is not clear what you are asking. And address all my comments.