# Relational algebra to find rows that do not have matches

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I have three relations:

```
Course(courseNum, units, time, room)
Student(ID, name, degree)
Takes(ID, courseNum)
```

I need a relational algebra expression that shows a list of courses that have no graduate student plus associated information (courseNum, units, time, room).

How can I use the relational algebra to find a relation that indicates "this course does not have grad students"?

Comment: What "relational algebra" are you using? There are many. Also in this design you have not told us what tuples go in the relations in a given situtation. So how can we know how to even restrict Student to grad students? Please google 'stackexchange homework' & show what parts you are able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I use the relational algebra to find a relation that indicates this course does not have grad students?

`R MINUS S` holds rows that are in R but not in S.

So if R with attributes r1, ... holds tuples that make a true *proposition* (statement) from some *(characteristic) predicate* (sentence template) *r* parameterized by r1, ... and S with attributes r1, ... holds tuples that make a true proposition from some predicate *s* in terms of r1, ... then `R MINUS S` holds tuples that make a true proposition from predicate *`r`*`AND NOT`*`s`*.

Similarly `JOIN` corresponds to `AND`, `UNION` to `OR`, `PROJECT`*`attributes kept`* to `EXISTS`*`attributes dropped`*, `RESTRICT`*`condition`* to `AND`*`condition`*, etc. That is how we know how to build a particular query--we use relation operators that return the tuples we want given that the base/named relations hold (via updates) the tuples satisfying their predicates (per the design).

(To use `MINUS` & `UNION` we sometimes have to rearrange a predicate expression to get argument expressions with the same attributes. And we have get any `NOT`s to appear in `AND NOT`. Often this is done by applying De Morgan's laws & distributive laws. [Find the names of students who are not enrolled in any course - Students, Faculty, Courses, Offerings, Enrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022424/3404097))

[Relational algebra for banking scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423150/relational-algebra-for-banking-scenario/24425914#)
[Forming a relational algebra query from an English description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318188/3404097)
[Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)