# Find the names of students who are not enrolled in any course - Students, Faculty, Courses, Offerings, Enrolled

Tags: relational-algebra

> Given the database below, project the names of the students who are not enrolled in a course using relational algebra.
>
> ```
> Students(snum, sname, major, standing, age, gpa)
> Faculty(fid, fname, deptid)
> Courses(cnum, cname, course_level, credits)
> Offerings(onum, cnum, day, starttime, endtime, room, max_occupancy, fid)  
> Enrolled(snum, onum)
> ```

I can get the snum of all students not enrolled in a course with:

```
π snum Students - π snum Enrolled
```

But how do I project the sname of the student with the snums that I find?

Comment: Hi. Please give a reference to what relational algebra you are supposed to use, because there are many versions, with different operators & notions of relation. Then read about joins. Re querying see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318188/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

Every base table holds the rows that make a true *proposition* (statement) from some *(characteristic) predicate* (statement template parameterized by columns). The designer gives the predicates. The users keep the tables updated.

```
-- rows where student [snum] is named [sname] and has major [major] and ...
Students
-- rows where student [snum] is enrolled in offering [onum]
Enrolled
```

Every query result holds the rows that make a true proposition from some predicate. The predicate of a relation expression is combined from the predicates of its argument expressions depending on its predicate nonterminal. The DBMS evaluates the result.

```
/* rows where
    student [snum] is named [sname] and has major [major] and ...
AND student [snum] is enrolled in offering [onum]
*/
Student ⨝ Enrolled
```

`AND` gives `NATURAL JOIN`, `AND`*`condition`* gives `RESTRICT`*`condition`*, `EXISTS`*`columns`* gives `PROJECT`*`other columns`*. `OR` & `AND NOT` with the same columns on both sides give `OR` & `MINUS`. Etc.

```
/* rows where
THERE EXISTS sname, major, standing, age & gpa SUCH THAT
    student [snum] is named [sname] and has major [major] and ...
*/
π snum Students

/* rows where
THERE EXISTS onum SUCH THAT
    student [snum] is enrolled in offering [onum]
*/
π snum Enrolled

/* rows where
    (   THERE EXISTS sname, major, standing, age & gpa SUCH THAT
            student [snum] is named [sname] and has major [major] and ...
    AND NOT
        THERE EXISTS onum SUCH THAT
            student [snum] is enrolled in offering [onum]
    )
AND student [snum] is named [sname] and has major [major] and ...
*/
(π snum Students - π snum Enrolled) ⨝ Students
```

You can project out any columns that you don't want from that.

(Notice that we don't need to know constraints to query.)

[Relational algebra for banking scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097)
[Forming a relational algebra query from an English description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318188/3404097)
[Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)