# How to represent GROUP BY with HAVING COUNT(*)>1 in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

For an exam, I am asked to get the list of clients having more than one rent, both as an SQL query and as an algebraic expression.

For some reasons, the correction doesn't provide the algebraic version.

So now I am left with:

```
SELECT IdClient, Name, ...
FROM Client
WHERE IdClient IN (
    SELECT IdClient 
    FROM Rental
    GROUP BY IdClient
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

I don't know if there is a standard for algebraic notations, therefore:

- Π projection
- × Cartesian product
- ⋈ natural join
- σ selection

Then I translate as:

```
Π IdClient, Name, ... (
    σ (count(IdClient)>1) (Π Rental) ⋈ (Client ⋈ Rental)
)
```

But I find no source to prove me right or wrong, especially for:

- the logic behind the math
- `Π Rental` seems like a shady business

I saw the use of `count()` at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/use-count-in-relational-algebra and while it isn't used the same way, I couldn't figure out a way to use it without the projection (which I wanted to avoid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many variants of "relational algebra", differing even on what a relation is. You need to tell us which one you are supposed to use.

Also you don't explain what it means for a pair of RA & SQL queries to "have the form of" or "be the same as" each other. (Earlier versions.) [Same result? Or also some kind of parallel structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411096/3404097)

Also you don't explain what "get the list of clients" means. What *attributes* does the result have?

If you try to write a definition of the `count` you are trying to use in `σ count(IdClient)>1 (...)`--what it inputs & what it outputs based on that--you will see that you can't. That kind of `count` that takes just an attribute does not correspond to a relational operator. It is used in a grouping expression--which you are missing. Such `count` & `group` are not actually relational operators, they are non-terminals in so-called relational algebras that are really query languages, designed by SQL apologists, suggesting it is easy to map SQL to relational algebra, but begging the question of how we aggregate in an algebra. Still, maybe that's the sort of "relational algebra" you were told to use.

> I saw the use of count() there https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/use-count-in-relational-algebra

The nature of algebras is that the only sense in which we "use" operators "with" other operators is to pass outputs of operator calls as inputs to other operator calls. (Hence some so-called algebras are not.) In your linked answer, grouping operator `G` inputs aggregate name `count` and attribute name `name` and that affects the output. The answer quotes Database System Concepts, 5th Ed:

> ```
>  G1, G2, ..., Gn G F1(A1), F2(A2), ..., Fm(Am) (E)
> ```
>
> where E is any relational-algebra expression; G1, G2, ..., Gn constitute a list of attributes on which to group; each Fi is an aggregate function; and each Ai is an attribute name.

`G` returns rows with attributes `G1, ..., A1, ...` where one or more rows with the same `G1, ...` subrows are in `E` and each `Ai` holds the output from aggregating `Fi` on `Ai` over those rows.

But the answer when you read & linked it used that definition improperly. (I got it fixed since.) Correct is:

```
π name (σ phone>1 (name G count(phone) (Person)))
```

This is clear if you carefully read the definition.

`G` has misleading syntax. `count(phone)` is not a call of an operator; it's just a pair of arguments, an aggregate name `count` & an attribute name `phone`. Less misleading syntax would be

```
π name (σ phone>1 (name G count phone (Person)))
```

One does not need a grouping operator to write your query. That makes it all the more important to know what "relational algebra" means in the exam. It is *harder* if you can't use a grouping operator.

"`Π Rental` seems like a shady business" is unclear. You do use projection incorrectly; proper use is `π attributes (relation)`. I guess you are using `π` in an attempt to involve a grouping operator like `G`. Re "the logic behind the math" see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097).

Comment: If you edit, please don't invalidate my answer. I wrote it from my comments even though your question is unclear so I can use it as a reference for all the other unclear questions that don't say what algebra they're using, don't say what "translate/convert" means, don't say what columns they want and/or don't understand syntax. I can add whatever you need (if you can use `count` & `group`, I don't know what more you need), but I suggest it would be better if you ask a new, clear question for concise answers & edit in a link here to it (to avoid downvotes & get upvotes). PS Edited my answer.