# breakdown complex data structure and assign product names

Tags: javascript

The `data` object below contains information about `products`, `customers` & `purchases`.

```
const data = {
  products: [
    {
      id: "p01",
      name: "Bike Insurance",
    },
    {
      id: "p02",
      name: "Car Insurance",
    },
    {
      id: "p03",
      name: "Home Insurance",
    },
    {
      id: "p04",
      name: "Pet Insurance",
    },
  ],
  customers: [
    { id: "c01", firstname: "Rachel", lastname: "Jane" },
    { id: "c02", firstname: "Leilah", lastname: "Mandi" },
    { id: "c03", firstname: "Campbell", lastname: "Kendall" },
    { id: "c04", firstname: "Madonna", lastname: "Sammie" },
  ],
  purchases: [
    {
      customerId: "c01",
      purchases: [
        {
          productId: "p02",
          purchasedAt: "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          productId: "p02",
          purchasedAt: "2021-08-04T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          productId: "p01",
          purchasedAt: "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          productId: "p01",
          purchasedAt: "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      customerId: "c03",
      purchases: [
        {
          productId: "p04",
          purchasedAt: "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          productId: "p04",
          purchasedAt: "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          productId: "p03",
          purchasedAt: "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
        {
          productId: "p01",
          purchasedAt: "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      customerId: "c02",
      purchases: [
        {
          productId: "p01",
          purchasedAt: "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I have so far filtered out the customers who have made purchases by using the following code:

```
const customersWhoPurchased = data["customers"].filter((c) =>
  data["purchases"].find((p) => p.customerId === c.id)
)
```

so the `customersWhoPurchased` now looks like this:

```
[ { id: 'c01', firstname: 'Rachel', lastname: 'Jane' },
  { id: 'c02', firstname: 'Leilah', lastname: 'Mandi' },
  { id: 'c03', firstname: 'Campbell', lastname: 'Kendall' } ]
```

What is the reasoning finding a query to go through the purchases for each customer in the `data` object, checking `productId` in the `purchases.purchases` array and matching that up to the `products` and then returning the `name` of each product the customer has purchased and adding them into an additional key value pair in the `customersWhoPurchased` array, with the value being an array of each product name?

Result:

```
customers: [
  { id: "c01", firstname: "Rachel", lastname: "Jane", productNames: ['Bike Insurance', 'Car Insurance'] },
  { id: "c02", firstname: "Leilah", lastname: "Mandi", productNames: ['Bike Insurance'] },
  { id: "c03", firstname: "Campbell", lastname: "Kendall", productNames: ['Bike Insurance', 'Home Insurance', 'Pet Insurance'] },
],
```

Comment: make a loop up so it is easier to get the names. `const productLookup = data.products.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item.id] = item.name, acc), {});` Just have to do a map over the purchases.

Comment: What's the specific issue you're having? You can either iterate the incoming `products` for each customers' purchases and gather product names, or load up a Map/object with product IDs => names and do the same thing for each customers' purchases.

Comment: [Re relational querying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create a hashtable-like structure for easy access:

```
const productsObj = data["products"].reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item;
    return obj
},{});
// {"p01":{"id":"p01","name":"Bike Insurance"},"p02":{"id":"p02","name":"Car Insurance"},"p03":{"id":"p03","name":"Home Insurance"},"p04":{"id":"p04","name":"Pet Insurance"}}

const customersObj = data["customers"].reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item;
    return obj
},{});
// {"c01":{"id":"c01","firstname":"Rachel","lastname":"Jane"},"c02":{"id":"c02","firstname":"Leilah","lastname":"Mandi"},"c03":{"id":"c03","firstname":"Campbell","lastname":"Kendall"},"c04":{"id":"c04","firstname":"Madonna","lastname":"Sammie"}}
```

Then, I would do something like this with the purchases, using the customer id as the key instead.

Consider that I am grouping purchases by the customer.

```
const purchasesGroupedByUser = data["purchases"].reduce((obj, item) => {
    // if first time finding this user
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(item.customerId)) {
        obj[item.customerId] = customersObj[item.customerId];
        obj[item.customerId].productNames = [];
    }

    const productNamesInCurrentPurchase = item.purchases.map(
        (product) => productsObj[product.productId].name
    );

    // updating productNames
    obj[item.customerId].productNames = obj[
        item.customerId
    ].productNames.concat(productNamesInCurrentPurchase);

    return obj;
}, {});
// {"c01":{"id":"c01","firstname":"Rachel","lastname":"Jane","productNames":["Car Insurance","Car Insurance","Bike Insurance","Bike Insurance"]},"c03":{"id":"c03","firstname":"Campbell","lastname":"Kendall","productNames":["Pet Insurance","Pet Insurance","Home Insurance","Bike Insurance"]},"c02":{"id":"c02","firstname":"Leilah","lastname":"Mandi","productNames":["Bike Insurance"]}}
```

And finally, convert to array:

```
const customersWithProductNames = Object.values(purchasesGroupedByUser);
// [{"id":"c01","firstname":"Rachel","lastname":"Jane","productNames":["Car Insurance","Car Insurance","Bike Insurance","Bike Insurance"]},{"id":"c03","firstname":"Campbell","lastname":"Kendall","productNames":["Pet Insurance","Pet Insurance","Home Insurance","Bike Insurance"]},{"id":"c02","firstname":"Leilah","lastname":"Mandi","productNames":["Bike Insurance"]}]
```