# How do the attributes suddenly came into play since the exercise statement didn't specify these two at the start?

Tags: database, relational-algebra

My exercise answer heavily relies on relational algebra procedural query language.

> Consider the following relational database schema:
>
> ```
> person(ID, firstName, lastName, nickName)
> follows(pID1, pID2)
> ```
>
> The relational instance person stores information for each person.  Each person is identified by their ID. The relational instance follows keeps track of who follows whom, i.e., pID1 follows
> pID2. The attributes pID1 and pID2 are both foreign keys to the attribute ID in the relation person
>
> Write a relational algebra query that finds all the pairs of nickNames (name1, name2), such that name1 follows name2.

How do the attributes `name1` and `name2` suddenly came into play since the exercise statement didn't specify these two at the start?

What do `name1` and `name2` represent (for instance, attributes or sub constituents of `nickName`)?

How am I supposed to use these two brand-new attributes while writing the relational algebra query?

My answer:

```
π nickName (σ pID1=ID ∧ pID2=ID (person ⨝ follows))
```

Breaking it down:

1. `person ⨝ follows` - Used the natural join operation (also named Cartesian product?) to combine the tables and ease the filtering process.
2. `σ pID1=ID ∧ pID2=ID` - Used the selection operation to filter out the names that don't respect the aforementioned order--"name 1 follows name 2"--associating the constraint to the ID attribute.
   c) `π nickName` - Retrieved just the column `nickName and its associated domains which are its encapsulated char-type values.

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Comment: Edit to 1 question. PS Ask whoever gave you your assignment what they meant. It's very sloppy. Complain. "(name1, name2)" is an example of one of "the pairs of nickNames" where "name1" & "name2" are names for the pair's 2 nicknames. Since a relational algebra query returns an n-ary relation the expectation is it's a 2-attribute relation with each tuple holding 2 nicknames. "name1 follows name2" is a sloppy way to say "in each pair/tuple the person with nickname name1 follows (in the app sense) the person with nickname name2". They might want "name1" & "name2" as return attributes--not clear.

Comment: [Re relational querying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a standard SQL database you're looking at something like

```
select distinct p1.nickName name1, p2.nickName name2
from follows f
join person p1 on p1.ID = f.pID1
join person p2 on p2.ID = f.pID2
```

Comment: Nop, unfortunately. I need something relational algebra based...

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the question(s) asked in the post. PS The question post does not have 1 question. Please don't answer unclear questions, flag as unclear. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts, When code is relevant to an answer, don't just dump it, explain how/why it answers the question. [answer] [ask] [Help] Also Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se].